# .htaccess redirect results in 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all traffic to `index.php`.

This is my `.htaccess` file code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /null.php [F,L]

php_value date.timezone "Asia/Jerusalem"
php_value expose_php off
php_value serversignature off
php_flag servertokens OS


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.js|\.css|\.txt|\.pdf|\.zip|\.doc|\.docx)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

I've checked that mod_rewrite is enabled in apache. All links I try on my domain gives 404. What am I missing?

Comment: With this code I would expect that you get the "Internal Error (500): Too many internal rewrites" error, not a 404 error. Your last rule should exclude index.php: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php`.